# What is the difference between "in operator" and "includes()" for JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I mean, `includes` is an Array prototype but `in` can be used with arrays too, so what is the main difference between both?

Comment: (as already pointed out below) the difference is they do different things.

Comment: The answer can be found with a little bit of research. You can study both of them using these links ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in
and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: `includes` is also a `String` method.

Answer (score 27):

[`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) checks for the existence of a value in an array, while the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) checks for the existence of a key in an object (or index in the case of arrays).

Example:

```js
var arr = [5];

console.log('Is 5 is an item in the array: ', arr.includes(5)); // true
console.log('do we have the key 5: ', 5 in arr); // false
console.log('we have the key 0: ', 0 in arr); // true
```

Comment: Why does the second console.log line return false while the third does not?

Comment: Since there is a single item in the array, the property `0` exists. However, since there aren't 6 items, index 5 doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

`Array#includes` determines whether a given value is an entry in the array. `in` checks to see if the given string is a known property of the object (or any of its prototypes). They are very different things.

> ..."in" can be used with arrays too...

It can, to check whether a property with a given name exists, but that's very different from what `includes` does:

```js
var a = [10];
console.log(a.includes(10)); // true, 10 is an entry in
console.log(10 in a);        // false, there's no property called "10" in the array
console.log(0 in a);         // true, there IS a property called "0" in the array
```

Using `in` on an array is a relatively unusual operation, mostly reserved for use on [*sparse* arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).

Answer (score 5):

"includes" checks whether a value exists in an array where as "in"
operator checks whether a key/index exists in obj/array.

```js
var arr = [15, 27, 39, 40, 567],
  obj = {
    num1: 3,
    num2: 34,
    num3: 89
  };;
console.log(arr.includes(27)); // returns true checks 27 as a value in the array
console.log(2 in arr);         // returns true checks 2 as index in the array
console.log("num1" in obj);    // returns true checks num1 as key in obj
```

Answer (score 3):

With `in` operator you can check if key exists, with `includes()` you can check if value exists